# input file is not inserted in multi-dimensional array from form elements when posted in Laravel Input class

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I am doing some multiple file upload. I have elements in my form like ( Im using blade here and removed design related html elements)

```
{{ Form::open(array('route' => 'cpanel.training_schedules.upload', 'files' => true)) }}
     @foreach ($trainingSchedules as $trainingSchedule)
         <input type="file" name="data[{{ $trainingSchedule->id }}][file]">
         <input type="hidden" name="data[{{ $trainingSchedule->id }}][reference]" value="{{$trainingSchedule->Course->reference}}">
         <input type="hidden" name="data[{{ $trainingSchedule->id }}][start_date]" value="{{$trainingSchedule->start_date}}">
     @endforeach
     <input type="submit" value="upload" class="btn btn-primary">
{{ Form::close() }}
```

When I submit this form, What I get when I try to dump the Input::all() is

```
array(2) [
    '_token' => string (40) "7UYMf87Nm1wLilJaQX0wLawwO1jxH56EceRRE08P"
    'data' => array(14) [
        '3' => array(2) [
            'reference' => string (5) "IE928"
            'start_date' => string (19) "2013-10-27 00:00:00"
        ]
        '4' => array(2) [
            'reference' => string (5) "FE160"
            'start_date' => string (19) "2013-12-15 00:00:00"
        ]
        '5' => array(2) [
            'reference' => string (5) "EE817"
            'start_date' => string (19) "2013-11-24 00:00:00"
        ]
        '6' => array(2) [
            'reference' => string (5) "EE817"
            'start_date' => string (19) "2013-11-24 00:00:00"
        ]
        '7' => array(2) [
            'reference' => string (5) "EE817"
            'start_date' => string (19) "2013-12-01 00:00:00"
        ]
        '8' => array(2) [
            'reference' => string (5) "EE817"
            'start_date' => string (19) "2013-11-27 00:00:00"
        ]
        '9' => array(2) [
            'reference' => string (5) "EE817"
            'start_date' => string (19) "2013-11-27 00:00:00"
        ]
        '10' => array(1) [
            'file' => object SplFileInfo D:\xampp\htdocs\HawardSolutions
        ]
        '11' => array(1) [
            'file' => NULL
        ]
        '12' => array(1) [
            'file' => NULL
        ]
        '13' => array(1) [
            'file' => NULL
        ]
        '14' => array(1) [
            'file' => NULL
        ]
        '15' => array(1) [
            'file' => NULL
        ]
        '16' => array(1) [
            'file' => NULL
        ]
    ]
]
```

As you can see the 'file' key was not merged on the associative array [id][file].

What I want to achieve on the 'data' key is

```
'data' => array(14) [
        '3' => array(2) [
            'reference' => string (5) "IE928"
            'start_date' => string (19) "2013-10-27 00:00:00"
            'file' => object SplFileInfo D:\xampp\htdocs\HawardSolutions
        ]
        '4' => array(2) [
            'reference' => string (5) "FE160"
            'start_date' => string (19) "2013-12-15 00:00:00"
            'file' => object SplFileInfo D:\xampp\htdocs\HawardSolutions
        ]
        '5' => array(2) [
            'reference' => string (5) "EE817"
            'start_date' => string (19) "2013-11-24 00:00:00"
            'file' => object SplFileInfo D:\xampp\htdocs\HawardSolutions
        ]
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am still on Laravel 4.0.* where I cannot recreate the first input that you got, but could you post the generated HTML code of the form?

Comment: Id edit now my post to show the form.
make sure to make your form's enctype="multipart/form-data" you can achieve that by 'files' => true.

Comment: Have you tried using the Input::file for getting the files? http://laravel.com/docs/requests#files